# What is the class of linear transformations $A$ for which $\mathbf{1}$ (the vector whose components are all 1) lies in $\text{Ker}(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, terminology, linear-transformations

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ any number, $\mathbf{1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Then question is: is there a class of linear transforms  $T(x) = Ax$ for $\alpha\mathbf{1}\in \text{Ker}(A), \forall \alpha\in \mathbb{R}?$

> i.e. matrices such that $A(\alpha\mathbf{1}) = \mathbf{0}$

The reason for asking because these matrices seem to be hard to identify:

For example:
$$A_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ belongs to such class

As well as $$A_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 &0\end{bmatrix}$$

But not $$A_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 &1\end{bmatrix}$$

Does anyone know what type of matrices $A_1,A_2$ could fall into? Skew symmetric?

Comment: The $\alpha$ does matter: matrix multiplication is linear, so $A(\alpha \mathbf{1}) = \alpha A(\mathbf{1})$.  Put differently, the kernel is a subspace, so if $\mathbf{1} \in \ker(A)$, then $\alpha \mathbf{1} \in \ker(A)$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @SpamIAm I'm sure you meant "The $\alpha$ does not matter," and I agree.

Comment: @CatalinZara Whoops!  Yes, I most certainly meant it does *not* matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition is equivalent to the sum of the columns of $A$ being the zero vector.

Comment: I think it should be sum of rows

Comment: @yoyostein Look at $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ vs. $\begin{bmatrix} 1 &0  \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Multiplication to the right means operations on the columns of $A$.

Comment: hmm... isn't it the first one that gives the zero vector? Maybe it is a different convention for multiplication?

Comment: @yoyostein Precisely. It is also the first one that has the sum of the columns being the zero vector. Think "sum of column vectors," not "sum by columns."

Comment: I see... thanks. +1

Comment: Good answer, but sadly there is no name for such class of matrices